# Logging time stamp of last update for every record

Tags: c, database, triggers, sqlite

I am using an sqlite3 database in Linux. I want to log the last update time stamp for every record. Can any one suggest me a way to automate this process?

Comment: Do you already log the timestamp of the last change to your table?

Comment: No I am not logging the time stamp of last update. Currently I am logging created time stamp by using the key words "default" and "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a table with a `timestamp` column. Every time you do something to a row in your column, you need to execute an UPDATE statement on that row, such as

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

Comment: Now we need to send the date and time stamp in the query.Is there any keyword to automatically update the column value(to current date and time) when ever the content of row got updated?